# change background color youtube embed inside iframe

Tags: jquery, css, iframe, youtube, embed

I want to change the background color of the youtube embed in a website i'm building. I'm trying to make it white so it blends in beter.

I've tried selecting the iframe with jquery and thus selecting the div responsible for the background color, but no luck here.

Anybody has an idea how to do this? Is it even possible to change content inside an iframe you don't control?

Comment: Can you provide the code you have tried and desired outcome?

Comment: Is there any possibility you can post an example of your code in plunker or jsfiddle or some other online-code tool? FYI, for security reasons you cannot change an `iframe` element from a different domain.